# Identifying Open Areas in OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap, area, identify

I am currently creating a system using OpenStreetMap (OSM) and I need to identify open areas in the map.

I know there are existing open areas on OSM but is there a way to identify more open areas that are not pre-identified using OSM data? 
Or can I do this using a different approach?

By open areas I mean, open fields, parks, or any areas away from structures like buildings

Comment: What do you mean by "open area"? Can you say what you're really trying to do?

Comment: Hi thank you for responding. By open area I mean, open fields, parks, or any areas away from structures like buildings.

Comment: Structures aren't that complete in OSM, so this won't be possible in general. For what purpose are you trying to identify these? Example: for landing helicopters in humanitarian situation?

Comment: Depending on what resolution you need and the size of candidate open areas, I would probably try using remote sensing data to avoid biasing the information by OSM's relative levels of spatial information completeness (which is far from 100% and very, very difficult to gauge).